# Writing a nested iterator of depth d

Tags: go, iterator, channel

How to realize a nested iterator that takes a depth argument. A simple iterator would be when depth = 1. it is a simple iterator which runs like a simple for loop.

```
func Iter () chan int {
    ch := make(chan int);
    go func () {
        for i := 1; i < 60; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    } ();
    return ch
}
```

Output is `1,2,3...59`

For depth = 2 Output would be `"1,1" "1,2" ... "1,59" "2,1" ... "59,59"`

For depth = 3 Output would be `"1,1,1" ... "59,59,59`"

I want to avoid a nested for loop. What is the solution here ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a nested loop? And what would be the return type if `Iter()` takes a `depth` argument?

Comment: @icza nested loop doesnt let me write a generic iterator of depth d? I am fine with string with ints joined by ,

Comment: @user568109: Early experiments using goroutine iterators  in the Go standard library were abandoned. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @peterSO I just wanted a way to compose iterations without recursion. Iterators are what I could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to avoid nested loops, but one solution is to use a pipeline of channels. For example:

```
const ITER_N = 60

// ----------------

func _goFunc1(out chan string) {
    for i := 1; i < ITER_N; i++ {
        out <- fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
    }
    close(out)
}

func _goFuncN(in chan string, out chan string) {
    for j := range in {
        for i := 1; i < ITER_N; i++ {
            out <- fmt.Sprintf("%s,%d", j, i)
        }
    }
    close(out)
}

// ----------------

// create the pipeline
func IterDepth(d int) chan string {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    go _goFunc1(c1)

    var c2 chan string
    for ; d > 1; d-- {
        c2 = make(chan string)
        go _goFuncN(c1, c2)
        c1 = c2

    }
    return c1
}
```

You can test it with:

```
func main() {
    c := IterDepth(2)

    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. This is what I was looking for. I did nt know the terminology is called pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement iterators using closures. Multiple dimensions don't make the problem much harder. Here's one example of how to do this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func iter(min, max, depth int) func() ([]int, bool) {
    s := make([]int, depth)
    for i := range s { 
        s[i] = min 
    }   
    s[0] = min - 1 
    return func() ([]int, bool) {
        s[0]++
        for i := 0; i < depth-1; i++ {
            if s[i] >= max {
                s[i] = min 
                s[i+1]++
            }   
        }   
        if s[depth-1] >= max {
            return nil, false
        }   
        return s, true
    }   
}   

func main() {
    // Three dimensions, ranging between [1,4)
    i := iter(1, 4, 3)
    for s, ok := i(); ok; s, ok = i() {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }   

}
```

Try it out on the [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/CkYDnIl-Wl).

It'd be a simple change for example to give arguments as a single int slice instead, so that you could have per-dimension limits, if such a thing were necessary.